# MySqlException: Subquery returns more than 1 row, for a stored procedure with a cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

Hello I have the following stored procedure for MySQL but when it is executed in my ASP.NET Core application I get a Subquery returns more than 1 row error. What am I doing wrong here? The equivalent SQL Server version used to work without problems...

```
-- System Calculates Candidate’s Matching Score based on a Manager’s Answer Weights
CREATE PROCEDURE spSysCalcCandScore
(
    IN Candidate_ID INT,
    IN Manager_ID INT
)
Begin
    DECLARE ansID INT;
    DECLARE tempSum INT;
    DECLARE Sum INT;
    DECLARE Done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Answer_ID FROM Completed_Questionnaire
    WHERE Candidate_ID = Candidate_ID;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Done = TRUE;
    START TRANSACTION;
        OPEN MyCursor;
        myloop: LOOP
            FETCH  MyCursor INTO ansID;
            IF Done THEN
                LEAVE myloop;
            END IF;
            SET tempSum = (SELECT Weight_Value FROM Weight WHERE (Answer_ID = ansID AND Manager_ID = Manager_ID));
            SET Sum = Sum + tempSum;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE MyCursor;
        
        IF (Sum IS NULL) THEN
            SET Sum = 0;
        END IF;
        
        UPDATE `Interest`
        SET Matching_Score = Sum
        WHERE (Candidate_ID = Candidate_ID AND Manager_ID = Manager_ID);
    COMMIT;
End//
```

Comment: I doubt you need a cursor anyway. Explain what you do and there will probably be a single query to do it. And this line may be producing the error: `SET tempSum = (SELECT Weight_Value FROM Weight WHERE (Answer_ID = ansID AND Manager_ID = Manager_ID));`

Comment: And don't name your parameters exactly like the column names!

Comment: Hm, I don't think this line is wrong since the combination of Answer and Manager ID for the table Weight is the primary key for that table so I should get 1 result on every SELECT. What I am doing here is taking the answer id of every answer submitted by a candidate (stored in Completed_Questionnaire table) and then take and add the weights put by a specific manager on each answer to calculate a matching score. Fair point about the parameter names I shall change them thank you!

Comment: 'so I should get ' - you really should check if this is true and if no then top 1

Comment: @AKaramitsos: `Manager_ID = Manager_ID` - how should the DB know which to take? The column with that name or the variable with that name? That condition is probably TRUE for ALL records since it takes the same thing twice like `1 = 1`

Comment: Yes you are right I noticed that it selected all records when the names were the same but oddly I had issues on this stored procedure and one 1 other only. All others were fine with same names. As was the case in t-sql in which I originally wrote my script with no naming issues. I also added `table_name`. in front of the column names as I saw in another stack answer to be sure and it all works fine now. The differences between sql and t-sql logic confused me somewhat. Thank you again for your time!